# Mapping RefSeq-ID or NCBI-ID (Entrez-ID) to EC number

Tags: sequence-annotation, identifiers, phylogenetics, refseq

I annotated my bacterial genomes using the new [NCBI Prokaryotic Genome Annotation Pipeline](https://github.com/ncbi/pgap) and now, I want to annotate EC-numbers.

In the master annotation file (.gff), I get the RefSeq-ID of every successful annotation, e.g. `RefSeq:YP_805528.1`.

When I visit the [respective NCBI page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=YP_805528.1), I see that it sometimes is mapped to an EC number.

I'd like to automate this process: Convert every RefSeq-ID to an EC number. How can I do this?

(I may already have discovered the first step: I can map the RefSeq-ID to the NCBI-ID (Entrez-ID) using this [NCBI conversion database](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/DATA/gene2refseq.gz): `YP_805528.1 -> 4419225`. But I don't see how to get from [these](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/DATA/) [databases](http://barc.wi.mit.edu/entrez_gene/entrez_gene.pdf) to EC.)

Are there other ways? As far as I know, most people blast their genes to already-mapped databases [like SwissProt and ExPASy ENZYME](http://breathmintsforpenguins.blogspot.com/2014/07/using-swissprot-and-expasy-enzyme-to.html). But I don't like this approach because technically, the NCBI annotation pipeline already did this. Why compute the same thing twice?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Entrez Direct](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/) for this as follows:

```
efetch -db protein -id YP_805528.1 -format gpc -mode xml | xtract -insd Protein EC_number
YP_805528.1     6.3.2.13
```